TALLY XML API ISSUE
Here I'am using the alterid staticly, but i need latest data of that vouchers,stockitems and customers here are the schemas, i'am using in it.
How can i pass the alterid dynamically to get the latest data.
Every I try to get the data through XML api, through below schemas ,i need updated data based in the alterid or any other way.
`<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>enter code here
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>COLLECTION</TYPE>
        <ID>CUSTOMVOUCHERDATA</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="CUSTOMVOUCHERDATA">
                        <TYPE>VOUCHER</TYPE>
                        <FETCH>VOUCHERNUMBER,DATE,ISCANCELLED,PARTYNAME,PARTYLEDGERNAME,PARTYGSTIN,CONSIGNEEGSTIN,LEDGERENTRIES.LIST,ALLLEDGERENTRIES,AMOUNT,VCHSTATUSDATE,EFFECTIVEDATE,ALTERID,MASTERID,VOUCHERKEY,VOUCHERRETAINKEY,GUID,BASICSHIPDOCUMENTNO,BASICFINALDESTINATION,BASICSHIPVESSELNO,EICHECKPOST,BILLOFLADINGNO,BILLOFLADINGDATE,BILLOFLADINGDATE,BASICSHIPPEDBY,IRN,IRNACKDATE,GSTREGISTRATION,VOUCHERTYPENAME,CMPGSTREGISTRATIONTYPE,CMPGSTSTATE,NUMBERINGSTYLE,VCHSTATUSTAXUNIT,GSTNATUREOFRETURN</FETCH>
                        <FILTER>Masterfilter</FILTER>
                    </COLLECTION>
                    <SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="Masterfilter">$MASTERID > 829 AND $ALTERID > 1343</SYSTEM>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>



stockitem

<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>COLLECTION</TYPE>
        <ID>CUSTOMSTOCKITEMCOL</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="CUSTOMSTOCKITEMCOL">
                        <TYPE>STOCKITEM</TYPE>
                        <FETCH>NAME,GUID,GSTAPPLICABLE,GSTDETAILS.LIST,ALTERID,MRPDETAILS.LIST,BASEUNITS,ISDELETED,OPENINGBALANCE,OPENINGRATE</FETCH>
                        <FILTER>Masterfilter</FILTER>
                    </COLLECTION>
                    <SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="Masterfilter">$ALTERID > 1094</SYSTEM>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>


customers

<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>COLLECTION</TYPE>
        <ID>CUSTOMERDATA</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="CUSTOMERDATA">
                        <TYPE>LEDGER</TYPE>
                        <FETCH>NAME,PARENT,GUID,PARTYGSTIN,BILLCREDITPERIOD,LEDGERMOBILE,LEDGERCOUNTRYISCODE,ISDELETED,ALTERID,EMAIL,PRIORSTATENAME</FETCH>
                        <FILTER>Masterfilter</FILTER>
                    </COLLECTION>
                    <SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="Masterfilter">$ALTERID > 32</SYSTEM>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>


you need save alterId in some database or file and populate it using some programming lang
